# How does a live server gets updated?

Tags: sql-server, rest, web-services, sql-server-2008

I want to know how does a server gets updated. like a live server without disrupting the users requests or freezing the site. how does it updates continually without making users to face the problem while it is updating. I think, I repeated the same thing twice. sorry about that. could you please answer my question. I desperately want to know the answer from you all.

Comment: What does "updating" mean? Do you mean updating data? Changing a table's structure? Changing code? Patching SQL Server? Patching the OS? Please be explicit, since many things can be updated, the disruption to users varies, and the mitigation can also vary.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Depending what sort of update you are talking about, if you're hosted on a managed server and they are doing a hardware update another server will take over the operation. If you are talking about software (again, depending on what) the server will remain active but may have a reduced speed or functionality.